# jquery adding .active to bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some issues with my existing jQuery when it comes to appending **.active** class to the Bootstrap navbar element, based on the browser url parameters.

The problem is that index.php will yield active class for the navbar element matching index.php however if no index.php is present the element will not be displayed as active, the same problem seems to occur when passing a query.

For example inbox.php will yield **.active** class, while inbox.php?view=sent will yield nothing.

Here is the existing jQuery can someone help me out to correct this tiny issues with index.php and / not displaying **.active** and same with links that contain query parameters for the same page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
        $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
             return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

The .nav structure is that of default Bootstrap navigation, nothing fancy. I have attempted to use PHP to append **.active** class but for some reason it did not want to play nicely and I used code that is found on StackOverflow regarding PHP and adding **.active** element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your pages have a path similar to `.../myPage.ext?x=y`, where `ext` is any given page extension i.e. `php, html, etc.`,  the following snippet gets the current page, removes the query string if any by splitting the `window.location` at `'?'` and gets the name of the current page, then it searches the `nav-bar` for the `<a></a>` with the matching `href`. Very similar to what you are doing.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Let's get rid of the query string
        var path = location.pathname.split('?')[0];
        var start = path.lastIndexOf('/');
        var activeLink = path.substr(start);

        var parent = $('a[href*="' + activeLink + '"]').parent('li');
        // These two lines check if you have dropdowns in your nav-bar
        if (parent.closest('ul').hasClass('dropdown-menu')) {
            parent.parents('.dropdown').addClass('active');
        }
        parent.addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the Query part. Any suggestions for the index.php and non-index ex: site.ltd vs site.ltd/index.php still dosent wan't to add .active on non index

Comment: @0111010001110000 I've updated my answer to get rid of the extension. It's easier to remove the query string first using split and then we just need to look for the last '/'. Let me know if this is what you were referring to.

Comment: That works just as well as before. but I still can't get .active class to show on example.com vs example.com/index.php, it's fine truth. I will just have index.php point the user to dashboard.php that way it will always be active :)

Comment: @0111010001110000 I see... what is the href that redirects you to the home page, the one without index.php like example.com? Is it href="/"? Or are you using an MVC framework with the routing and the works?

Comment: Yep, it's just a regular href="/" for navbrand and navbar which send user back to dashboards default page. And nope no MVC or routing

Comment: @0111010001110000 I've updated my answer to include the '/' when it initializes the start variable. Can't test the code right now but I think this should do it