# how to change .active class in bootstrap using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

i am using django, and try to create a base template. I want to change the .active class in navbar links which points to a seperate link, 
Eg. Home link in navbar points to home.html, About Us link in navbar points to about.html.

I have also used a code in jquery to do that but it is not working. Please suggest any method to do that.

Please don't bother i am a newbie!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | Vasu Genset Pvt. Ltd.</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'index/css/index.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'index/css/products-style.css' %}">

    {% block style %}{% endblock %}


</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home/" >Vasu Genset Pvt. Ltd.</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mydropdown">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mydropdown">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navbar-change">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/aboutus/">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/productsandservices/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products & Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/generatorrepair/">Generator Repair</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/generatormaintenance/">Generator Maintenance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/alternator/">Alternator Repair & Maintenance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/amc/">AMC Service Provider</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/spareparts/">Spare Parts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/generatorrentalhire/">Generator Rental & Hire</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/synchronizing/">Synchronizing Panel</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/amfpanel/">AMF Panel</a></li>
                            <li><a href="acousticenclosures">Acoustic Enclosures</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/contactus/">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}

    <footer class="text-center">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                        <h4>Copyright &copy; Vasu Genset Pvt. Ltd.</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </footer>


</body>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static 'index/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.nav li').click(function(e) {

                $('.nav li').removeClass('active');

                var $this = $(this);
                if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
                    $this.addClass('active');
                }
                //e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>



</html>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/40139062/6383857 out, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

your code works but it will trigger x time in x-nested ul li (uncomment the line to see in the console  what's happened when you click). Depending on the behaviour you expect, just stop event propagation can do the trick.  (plus `if (!$this.hasClass('active'))` will always return true as you have just removed all class 'active' in all li contained in nav).

```js
$('.nav  li').click(function(e) {
  //console.log(e.currentTarget,"//",e.target,"//",this);
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Vasu Genset Pvt. Ltd.</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mydropdown">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mydropdown">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navbar-change">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products & Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#/">Generator Repair</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/">Generator Maintenance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/">Alternator Repair & Maintenance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/">AMC Service Provider</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/">Spare Parts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/">Generator Rental & Hire</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/">Synchronizing Panel</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/">AMF Panel</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#/">Acoustic Enclosures</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#/">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```